# No solutions Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I had this matrix below:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&4&2\\2&9&3\\-1&0&a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\b\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

And after some Gaussian operations I get this below:

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}1&4&2&1\\0&1&-1&b-2\\0&0&a+6&-4b+10\end{array}\right]$$

I can clearly see that when $a = -6$ there is no solutions but when I look in the answer it says below:

$$b\neq\frac{5}{2}$$

I don't understand why $b$ shouldn't become $5/2$ but if we say that $b = 2,\,0 = -4\cdot2 + 10 \implies 0 = 2$ it is also not a solution I don't understand why $b\neq5/2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=-6$, then what you have is$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&4&2&1\\0&1&-1&b-2\\0&0&0&-4b+10\end{array}\right].$$If you see this as a system, then that system is$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+4y+2z=1\\y-z=b-2\\0=-4b+10.\end{array}\right.\tag1$$Clearly, if $b\ne\frac52$, then $-4b+10\ne0$ and so the system has no solution. Otherwise $(1)$ becomes$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+4y+2z=1\\y-z=\frac12\\0=0\end{array}\right.$$and it is not hard to see that it has solutions.

Comment: Carlos Santos Thanks!